# Time-complexity and cost of algorithms with nested loops and if statements

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

I am having some trouble figuring out the time complexity of the following algorithms,
these include nested loops and if statements with different conditions in them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if you don't mind, I'd like to ask how one tackles these problems. I need a way of telling the time-complexity of any algorithm in a mechanical way. What's the process of solving these like?

Here they are:

```
int s = 0;
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    if (i == j*j){
        for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k){
            ++s;
        }

        ++j;
    }
}
```

That's the "easy" one, then the one I find particularly hard is:

```
int s = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < i*i; ++j){
        if (j % i == 0){
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) ++s;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your time

TLDR: I am asking for the theta time-complexity of each algorithm: Θ(...)

Comment: A confusing bit of syntax: do you repeatedly increment j inside the loop over k or is that loop only governing s? This sort of thing makes this kind of question with code rather than pseudocode bad for a math audience.

Comment: That being said, if this works the way I think it works (where ++j is not inside the loop over k), then you can "cheat" by just running them and plotting s(n), which will have the same scaling as the number of operations. This will at least tell you the answer, regardless of being able to prove it.

Comment: Sorry for that @Ian, I am about to edit that. The ++j is outside the nested for loop

Comment: You could count all ops for a certain large n, increase n by ten, a hundred times and see what happens to the amount of ops? (I just noticed somebody suggested using size of "s" which is a good idea in this case)

Comment: In the first one you actually do something when $i$ is $0$, $1$, $4$, ... and in each of those instances you do $n$ operations. How many perfect squares are there from $0$ to $n$, roughly? Once you know this you can just multiply.

Comment: In the second one, for each $i$ you loop through $i^2$ values of $j$, and then you actually do order $n$ operations on the $j$'s that are divisible by $i$. How many such $j$'s are divisible by $i$, roughly? Once you know that you can just multiply to get the complexity of each iteration of the $i$ loop and then finally you need to sum that up over $i$. Finally you need to worry if the work needed to ignore the $j$'s that are *not* divisible by $i$ might be significant relative to the work done on the $j$'s that *are* divisible by $i$, since there are so much more of them when $i$ is large.